# How to add fields to the Avro schema in Apache NiFi?

Tags: json, csv, schema, avro, apache-nifi

I'm able to get Apache NiFi to generate a schema via the CSVReader, and then I can write the schema out to an attribute using ConvertRecord. However I then need to add fields using UpdateRecord, but the fields are not being added to the flow file or the to the schema attribute. I believe this is because the fields are not part of the initially inferred schema. I can't create the schema in the registry because it's being inferred from the file. So how can I add fields to a record when the schema doesn't include the fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using InferAvroSchema to not have to worry about generating the schema(s), or because you really will not know the schema of the CSV files? If the former, then send one CSV through, then copy the inferred schema into a CSVReader, and add the fields from UpdateRecord into the write schema.

I've written up [NIFI-5524](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5524) to cover the automation of adding/updating fields in the outgoing schema based on UpdateRecord properties.

Comment: I'm using it because I won't know the full schema of some of these until runtime. It's not practical to generate the schemas using the above method each time I get a new file. The main reason I'd want to use NiFi is to save time, and unfortunately that wouldn't save me much.

Comment: Seems the answer is basically that it's not currently possible. I'll mark this as accepted since it mentions the enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is because your **writer controller service doesn't have the new fields** defined in it.

If you are **adding new fields then we need to define new avro schema** with the additional fields included in the schema writer controller service.

Change the **Schema Access Strategy** to either

> **Use 'Schema Name' Property (or)  Use 'Schema Text' Property**

then Define your new schema including new fields in it so that Update Record processor will add the new fields to the output flowfile.

Please look into [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/189642/update-the-contents-of-flowfile-by-using-updaterec.html) article, as i have added **ts_tz,current_ts..etc** fields in it that doesn't exist in the input data and defined the **writer controller service** with the **new avro schema** that includes **all the new/old fields** in it.

Comment: I can't define the schema. It was generated automatically. I need to extend it or have it extended automatically.

Comment: ...more specifically, it was inferred by the processor. So I have no way of accurately redefining it.

Comment: Can't you copy the schema text from the flow file attribute and then make edits to it outside of NiFi and upload it to the schema registry?

Comment: No, because the schema changes at runtime. But on that note - how are you viewing the flow file attribute at runtime? In the logs? Or is there some nicer UI for monitoring this?

Comment: Nevermind! I see it in the Data Provenance interface.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same by adding columns to the CSV using replace text processor (this will add same values for header and values in the csv), use replacement mode "Line-By-Line" and then use update record to update values only of the new columns to something meaningful.

No need to know the schema beforehand using this approach.

[image]